# Bootstrap (half) xs col's?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i'm using bootstrap

I know that xs col's are the smallest size in bootstrap but what if i needed a breaking point ex 400px I want at that point something else ! how I do that ?

Comment: You can write media query for the same like @media (max-width: 400px) {
  .col-xs-4{
 //Write your own css
}
}

Comment: @MandeepSingh But that will overwrite every col-xs-4 classes !

Comment: It will only overwrite when your pixels are less than 400 px, that's what you need, to write your custom code when size is less than 400px

Comment: But other elements will be effected with this too, ex: div-social I want col-xs to be 3 cols and to be 1 col when it's 400px .... But div-authors I want it to be 3 cols all the time .... doing a media query will effect both and others

Comment: So write a more specific selector!

Comment: @Quentin da !! I totaly forget about it. Thank you and you too MandeepSingh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summing up in answer :

You can write media query for the same like

```
@media (max-width: 400px) { .col-xs-4{ //Write your own css } }
```

It will only overwrite when your pixels are less than 400 px, that's what you need, to write your custom code when size is less than 400px

Answer (score 0):

write your normal html and css while using bootstrap. and add extra media query some some custom columns.

```css
@media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .row .col-xss-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
/*for demo  */

[class*="col-"] {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-xss-6">
      on lowest width, it would be 100% while on other it would be 50% upto 768px .col-xss-6 will overwrite the default width property, but will take float:left, padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px and other imp. properties from col-xs-12 itself. */

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      this is without col-xss-6, so it will have default bootstrap properties.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```